# Android 6.0 : Foreground service is being removed when app is being killed

Tags: android, service, android-6.0-marshmallow

I created `Notification` in `onStartCommand` of my `Service` class to run a foreground service.

In previous versions of Android (version < 6.0) the service keeps running and the `Notification` can not be removed even if I kill the app from the recent apps menu. I'm also using `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent filter for my `BroadCastReceiver` so that my service starts as my device restarts. Everything is working fine in Lollipop and previous versions. But when I tested in my Marshmallow device, when I clear my ram from recent app, the foreground service is also killed and the *Irremovable Notification* also being removed. As a result my app stops working. Service does not start when the device restarts either.

Is it causing by the famous **DOZE MODE** implemented in Android 6.0 and Higher ? Or there is something else ? Please help me someone ? I asked for help earlier but couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Please guys....I am stuck

Comment: @FabioC Sir, Can you check on my problem please..?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. :( This was needed in one of my personal project. And now I can't manage time to work on it. I assume I need to use Job Scheduler/Alarm Manager type of thing. Do you have any available solution ?

Comment: Sadly, no... Google does small developers no favors with stuff like this.

Comment: In your onStartCommand() you have to return START_STICKY or REDELIVER_INTENT. 
Have a look on the documentation here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add process attribute in manifest

```
<service
 android:name=".YourServiceName"
 android:process=".process"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:exported="true"></service>
```